# Disable NSService context menu for multiple files selected in Finder

Tags: objective-c, macos, service, operating-system, finder

I use a `NSService` for my application: the user runs it from the Finder context menu. I need to disable this `NSService`'s context menu button for multiple selections.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. As the documentation says, possible values for the NSTextContent key are URL, Date, Address, Email, or FilePath - neither allows to specify any filter.